# show a list of word and definition using hashmap

Tags: java, list, random, hashmap

I am trying to create a simple game with with a list of words using hashmap. what i want to do is. i want to show the user a word from the list in a scrambling way. for example a word like hello would be "loeh". the user would have to enter his answers, and if the answer is right the user would get a point. can somebody tell how would be able to scramble the key in the map list to display to the user;

this is  the code i have so far;

```
public class Game extends Applet {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.applet.Applet#init()
 */

// create a list words with answers. probbaly a map list


Map<String, String> words =  new HashMap<String, String>();     
// add words and  definition to the  list
     words.put("HI", " A form Salutation");
```

Comment: Please remove the parts of the code that are unrelated to your question as they confuse readers and make the question unnecessary long

Answer (score 0):

Here is the concept I would go with.

```
for each letter in word
    listofletters.add(letter)

while(listofletters.notEmpty())
    scrambledword += listofletters.pop(RandomNum(0,listofletters.size))

print scambledword
```

pop here is both returning the letter and removing it from the list. If you code my psuedo code out into java and have errors post it back up as an edit and Ill help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String shuffle (String yourKey) {
    char tmp;
    char[] newStr = yourKey.toCharArray();
    Random r = new Random();
    int newPos;
    for (int i=0; i < yourKey.length(); i++) {
        newPos = r.nextInt(yourKey.length());
        tmp = newStr[i];
        newStr[i] = newStr[newPos];
        tab[newPos] = tmp;
    }
    return new String(newStr);
}
```

In the main code

```
String newStr = shuffle(yourKey);
while(newStr.compareTo(yourKey)==0) {
    newStr = shuffle(yourKey);
}
```